# formvalidation.io including hidden fields

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, formvalidation.io

I'm using `formvalidation.io` to validate my form before sending.
I also have some hidden fields that are created dynamically that I have to include into validation.

Two questions:

1. How can I validate these hidden fields created dynamically ?
2. How can I show errors of these hidden fields in a specific part of
   the form? Because if the fields are hidden, is not possible to show
   the error messages near the fields...

Here are my hidden fields created dynamically:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sectors[]" value="{{ json_encode(["id"=>$docSector->sector_id,"relation"=>$docSector->relation_type]) }}">
```

Comment: Why do you need to validate hidden fields? The user can't do anything with them. If they are generated based on the user's input, validate and display the error message at the place where the input is coming from.

Comment: Yes I know, I would to check it and prevent form send, but I didn't tried the way...if formvalidation validate the form, I don't know how to stop the submit...